# pivot_table gives me TypeError: unstack() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've noticed this error when trying to pivot_table, at first I suspected something is wrong with my Dataframe so I copied the example from the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html) but to my surprise i'm seeing the same error. this the example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar"],
                   "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two"],
                   "C": ["small", "large", "large", "small",
                         "small", "large", "small", "small",
                         "large"],
                   "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
                   "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})
table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns=['C'], aggfunc="sum")
```

Error :

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-e8dff429bcc3> in <cell line: 10>()
      8                    "D": [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
      9                    "E": [2, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9]})
---> 10 table = pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns=['C'], aggfunc="sum")

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in unstack(self, level, fill_value, sort)
   9620         return correl
   9621 
-> 9622     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   9623     # ndarray-like stats methods
   9624 

TypeError: unstack() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given
```

I'm using Pandas version 2.1.4 and Python 3.10.12 running on Google Colab.

Thank you in advance

Comment: For me working correct. One idea, can you test `pd.pivot_table(df, values='D', index=['A', 'B'], columns='C', aggfunc="sum")` ?

Comment: produces the same error.

Comment: So it should be bug.

Comment: I installed some libraries in this colab and upgraded pandas to 2.1.4, so it could be an issue with the installation.

Comment: You probably need to try again with a fresh colab.

Comment: I have the same problem with pandas 2.2.0. Is it a bug? Used to work in pandas 1.x